# Where can I find the Trapper?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

At various places in the game, someone called "the Trapper" is mentioned. After I completed some challenges, I got a notification that I unlocked a new item at the Trapper. I got a similar notification when killing and skinning the legendary bear.

I've played a while now, but I haven't seen the Trapper anywhere yet. Where exactly can I find him? Or is the Trapper connected to my progress in the main quest somehow?

Answer (score 3):

The map above is missing the main trapper in St. Denis.  There are 5 in total:

[image: RDR2 Trapper Map]

Here's an interactive version of the Trapper map above: http://rdr2map.com?catIds=15

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://static.gosunoob.com/img/1/2018/10/rdr2-trapper-locations.jpg) should be all Trapper locations:

[image]

Comment: For images you can actually embed the image as part of the body, which I've taken the liberty of doing. You can do this yourself by using the "Insert Image" button when writing / editing a post. Cheers!